# Mysql Join - Q&A tagging system - how to modify to show Tag and Answer counts, even for tags without cross references

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a Q&A scheme that uses tags.

I have a Mysql join query which uses 3 tables.

1. TAGS: tag_id, tag_name (originating tag associated to questions)
2. TAGS_X: tag_id, question_id (cross references tags to questions)
3. POSTS: question_id + other columns (answers to questions)
4. QUESTIONS: question_id + other columns, but NOT used in this SQL join

The TAGS table is the originating table of tag names.  Questions have tags, and Answers are posted on POSTS, based on the question ID.  The purpose of the query is to count the number of answers associated with the tag (indirectly through the question ID).

Some tags:

1. are new and not cross referenced yet to anything.  Want to list tag_id, tag_name, answer_count of 0. [DOES NOT LIST]
2. are associated with a Question, but DO NOT have an answer in POSTS, and question_id does NOT appear in POSTS, therefore, the answer count would be 0 [WORKS OK]
3. are associated with one or more questions, have answers in POSTS, and will have a count [WORKS OK]

The SQL code below works for situation #2 AND #3.  Is there a simple way to moidify the code below to make it work for situation #1 also, so tags without cross references, and without Answers, are also listed out?

```
$sql = "SELECT tags.tag_name AS tag_name, tags_x.tag_id AS tag_id, count(posts.question_id) as answer_count FROM tags_x    
    INNER JOIN tags
    ON tags.tag_id = tags_x.tag_id
    LEFT JOIN posts
    ON tags_x.question_id = posts.question_id
    GROUP BY tags_x.tag_id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(); 
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(pdo::FETCH_ASSOC);        
foreach($result as $row){
    $tag_id = $row['tag_id'];
    $tag_name = $row['tag_name'];
    $answer_count = $row['answer_count'];
    echo $tag_id.' - '.$tag_name.' - '.$answer_count.'<br>';//for testing
}
```

[edit]

Tried left joining:

```
SELECT tags.tag_name AS tag_name, tags_x.tag_id AS tag_id, count(posts.question_id) as answer_count FROM tags   
            LEFT JOIN tags_x
```

This modification worked per Akina's suggestion in answer below!

Comment: INNER JOIN is errorneous. It ejects records matched condition (1). GROUP BY by TAGS_X column is errorneous too, accompanying the first reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tag_id, tags.tag_name, COUNT(posts.question_id) AS answer_count
FROM tags
LEFT JOIN tags_x USING (tag_id)
LEFT JOIN posts USING (question_id)
GROUP BY tag_id, tags.tag_name
```

Comment: Tried your SQL code, but got exactly the same result - still not listing the tags that are NOT cross referenced in the tags_x table...

Comment: Hey, sorry per my previous comment , I was mistaken - the first hundred lines or so looked identical, but as I looked further down, the new entries appeared - your code corrections worked! Thank you.